# Delphi Android app has Accessibility issues on Google Play Console

Tags: android, delphi, accessibility, google-play-console

I have an Android app built with Delphi 11.2 that works fine on the devices. However, when I submit the app to Google Play Console for testing, their auto testing reports warnings about Accessibility problems. The **Pre-Launch report** has a red rectangle highlighting the full screen of the app under the **Content labeling** section, with the recommendation "This item may not have a label readable by screen readers."

So, I started up TalkBack on my Android device, and it does the same thing. It shows a blue highlight around the whole app screen. If I try to press any of the buttons on the screen, I hear a beep and the highlight remains around the whole screen and nothing happens. It is like there is some object overlaying the whole app screen and not allowing access to any of the controls under it.

When I look at my source code, the only items that cover the full screen are the form itself and a `TLayout` item set to `Client` of the form. All of the controls are placed on top of the `TLayout`.

Has anyone else had problems like this with Android apps build with Delphi? If so, what do I need to do to fix the problem for screen readers not having access to the controls?

Comment: It's because of the way FMX renders controls. Since they're not "native", accessibility features of Android cannot act on them. For now, the warning can be ignored. Delphi supports using some native controls (those where the `ControlType` property with a value of `Platform` applies), however if you want accessibility features for all controls, you may need to use another dev tool

Comment: Can you show the results of `adb shell uiautomator dump && adb shell cat /sdcard/window_dump.xml` - this will dump the rendered view hierarchy - if there aren't nested nodes, the problem might be Delphi itself. Can you share a link for writing Android Apps in Delphi for me so I can try it out?